# Why do I get the error Missing implementation of interface method in Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Consider the following code:

```
uses
  {... }
  ComObj,
  ShlObj;

type
  TContextMenu = class(TComObject, IShellExtInit, IContextMenu)
  private
  {(*}
  const
    GUID: TGUID = '{99D8B139-0855-4C5D-95E7-BC8EC6254B3D}';
  {*)}
  private
    FCmdCount: LongWord;
    FDm: Tdm_ContextMenu;
  protected
    function IShellExtInit.Initialize = IShellExtInit_Initialize;
    function IShellExtInit_Initialize(_pidlFolder: PItemIDList; _lpdobj: IDataObject;
      _HKeyProgID: HKEY): HResult; stdcall;
    function QueryContextMenu(_Menu: HMENU; _indexMenu, _idCmdFirst, _idCmdLast,
      _UFlags: UINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function InvokeCommand(var _ici: TCMInvokeCommandInfo): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetCommandString(_idCmd, _uType: UINT; _pwReserved: PUINT;
      _PszName: LPSTR; _cchMax: UINT): HResult; stdcall;
  public
    procedure Initialize; override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;
```

This compiles fine in Delphi 2007 and XE but Delphi XE2 gives me the error:
"[DCC Error] u_ContextMenuHandler.pas(16): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IContextMenu.GetCommandString"

This has me baffled. I checked the interface declaration and my GetCommandString function has the exactly the same declaration as the interface's. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'_idCmd' is declared `UINT_PTR` (which is 8 bytes when targeting 64-bit) in XE2.

Comment: Will delete this answer when David restores his.

Comment: @David - Well, ok, but yours is still more comprehensive :)

Comment: Argh, you are right! But it said "missing implementation" not "type mismatch". :-(

Comment: The compiler error is correct. The implementation of the interface function was indeed missing. In order to provide a valid implementation you need to match name, parameter list, return type and calling convention.

Answer (score 2):

The correct declaration of `GetCommandString` is:

```
function GetCommandString(idCmd: UINT_PTR; uFlags: UINT; pwReserved: PUINT;
  pszName: LPSTR; cchMax: UINT): HResult; stdcall;
```

Make sure that you check for the presence of `GCS_UNICODE` in `uFlags` before writing to `pszName`. That test determines whether or not you should return a Unicode or ANSI string. This nuance is described in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).