# Missing implementation for ToolsAPI interface method when upgrading to Delphi 10.4 Sydney

Tags: delphi, interface, toolsapi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have installed Delphi 10.4 Sydney w/ Patch 2 in a new virtual machine, and copied Delphi 10.3 Tokyo sources to it.

When rebuilding a visualizer (for DevExpress TcxSchedulerEvents) I get this error:

> [dcc32 Error] EventVisualizr.pas(19): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IOTAThreadNotifier.EvaluateComplete

I had only removed the compiled packages `cxLibraryRS26`, `cxSchedulerRS26`, `dxCoreRS26`, `dxGDIPlusRS26`, and added `cxLibraryRS27`, `cxSchedulerRS27`, `dxCoreRS27`, `dxGDIPlusRS27` - no other code changes:

[image]

I get the error on the first line of the `TEventViewerFrame` type definition:

```
unit EventVisualizr;
// Copied and modified from TStringListVisualizer. Shows values for TcxSchedulerEvent properties:
// - ID
// - Caption
// - Custom property tt_fromdate (if it exists)
// - Custom property tt_todate (if it exists)
// - Start
// - Finish

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ComCtrls, ToolsAPI, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TAvailableState = (asAvailable, asProcRunning, asOutOfScope, asNotAvailable);

  TEventViewerFrame = class(TFrame, IOTADebuggerVisualizerExternalViewerUpdater, IOTAThreadNotifier, IOTAThreadNotifier160)
    EventListView: TListView;
    procedure EventListViewData(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
  private
    FOwningForm: TCustomForm;
    FClosedProc: TOTAVisualizerClosedProcedure;
    FNotifierIndex: Integer;
    FCompleted: Boolean;
    FDeferredResult: string;
    FDeferredError: Boolean;
    FPropValues,
    FPropNames: TStrings;
    FAvailableState: TAvailableState;
    function Evaluate(Expression: string): string;
  protected
    procedure SetParent(AParent: TWinControl); override;
  public
    procedure CloseVisualizer;
    procedure MarkUnavailable(Reason: TOTAVisualizerUnavailableReason);
    procedure RefreshVisualizer(const Expression, TypeName, EvalResult: string);
    procedure SetClosedCallback(ClosedProc: TOTAVisualizerClosedProcedure);
    procedure SetForm(AForm: TCustomForm);
    procedure AddEventItems(const Expression, TypeName, EvalResult: string);

    { IOTAThreadNotifier }
    procedure AfterSave;
    procedure BeforeSave;
    procedure Destroyed;
    procedure Modified;
    procedure ThreadNotify(Reason: TOTANotifyReason);
    procedure EvaluteComplete(const ExprStr, ResultStr: string; CanModify: Boolean;
      ResultAddress, ResultSize: LongWord; ReturnCode: Integer);
    procedure ModifyComplete(const ExprStr, ResultStr: string; ReturnCode: Integer);

    { IOTAThreadNotifier160 }
    procedure EvaluateComplete(const ExprStr, ResultStr: string; CanModify: Boolean;
      ResultAddress: TOTAAddress; ResultSize: LongWord; ReturnCode: Integer);
  end;
```

In the `ToolsAPI.pas`, both have an `EvaluateComplete` definition, but no implementation in that source file:

```
IOTAThreadNotifier = interface(IOTANotifier)
  ['{34B2E2D7-E36F-11D1-AB0E-00C04FB16FB3}']
  { This is called when the process state changes for this thread }
  procedure ThreadNotify(Reason: TOTANotifyReason);
  { This is called when an evaluate that returned erDeferred completes.
    ReturnCode <> 0 if error }
  procedure EvaluateComplete(const ExprStr, ResultStr: string; CanModify: Boolean;
    ResultAddress, ResultSize: LongWord; ReturnCode: Integer);
  { This is called when a modify that returned erDeferred completes.
    ReturnCode <> 0 if error }
  procedure ModifyComplete(const ExprStr, ResultStr: string; ReturnCode: Integer);
end;

IOTAThreadNotifier160 = interface(IOTAThreadNotifier)
  ['{46F94C52-E225-4054-A5F0-F5E67E29B2C2}']
  { This is called when an evaluate that returned erDeferred completes.
    ReturnCode <> 0 if error }
  procedure EvaluateComplete(const ExprStr, ResultStr: string; CanModify: Boolean;
    ResultAddress: TOTAAddress; ResultSize: LongWord; ReturnCode: Integer); overload;
end;
```

When comparing ToolsAPI files, I see:

- It was named `EvaluteComplete` (missing 'a') in 10.3 and that has been fixed to `EvaluateComplete`
- The `IOTAThreadNotifier160.EvaluateComplete` now gets an overload directive (of course, and not relevant to the issue I think)

Could that name change be the reason? There are no 'implementation' for the `EvaluateComplete` procedures in the 10.3 version either (which seems to be fine, from the very little I know about interfaces).

From [Why do I get the error Missing implementation of interface method in Delphi XE2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373636/) and [Why do I get error Missing implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493182/), I understand that the reason for the error can be that the parameter lists differ, but I have no idea where to look for the correct ones in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `TEventViewerFrame` still contains the implementation for the 'old' `EvaluteComplete`.

Fix it by simply renaming `TEventViewerFrame.EvaluteComplete` to `TEventViewerFrame.EvaluateComplete` (to satisfy the new interface contract).